# Como abrir um projeto direto pelo explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu fiquei com a seguinte dúvida esses dias e não consegui achar uma solução pra isso.

Seguinte, eu tenho vários projetos no Android Studio (todos já foram importados e estão funcionando perfeitamente), porém, toda vez que eu abro o AS ele abre o último projeto que eu estava desenvolvendo, XXX pra facilitar, porém, se eu quiser abrir o projeto YYY eu tenho que abrir o AS, esperar carregar o projeto XXX, depois ir nos recentes, procurar o YYY e abrir ele por alí.

A questão é, existe algum jeito de abrir o projeto YYY direto pelo windows explorer, ou pelo menos sem ter que esperar carregar o projeto XXX? Um bom exemplo do que eu estou falando seria a "Solution" do Visual Studio, que basta abrir o arquivo *.sln que o VS vai abrir o projeto inteiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível abrir um "projecto" do Android Studio via Explorador de ficheiros.

O Android Studio, ao contrário de outros IDE's, não cria um arquivo de "projecto".

Se não quiser que o projecto anterior seja aberto pelo Android Studio, feche-o antes de sair ou, em `File->Settings`, desseleccione a opção ***Reopen last project on startup*** na janela **Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Conforme [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362036/how-to-prevent-open-last-projects-when-intellij-idea-start) resposta em inglês, existe uma configuração do Android Studio (AS) para desabilitar a reabertura do projeto mais recente:

> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Reopen last project on startup

Obs.: Na resposta original se menciona o Intellij mas também se aplica ao AS.